# How can I change the Index batch size of a ravenDB database from 512 to 1024

Tags: ravendb

As the title says I am trying to change the batch size of my raven db database. This sounds like it should be something really simple but I can't seem to work out how to do it. I have searched google and looked over the ravenDB Console.

My problem is when I try to populate a ravenDB database I only get a fraction of the documents but when I populate a ravenDB database on a test server I seem to get all of the documents.

I was looking at the status page of the ravenDB console and it turns out the database on the test server has and Index count of 6 while the ravenDB database on my local machine has 7. The test server has a document count of 63,864 while my machine has 28,512. The database on the test server has an Index Batch Size of 1,024 while the database on my machine only has an Index batch size of 512.

I'm not sure why there are differences as I use the same code to generate the databases. I am still relatively new to RavenDB. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand if the problem is on the number of results when querying or it is on the index batch size but:

For the number of results when querying the difference could be in the server configuration.
Check if in the server config file *[YourRavenDbFolder]/Server/Raven.Server.exe.config* is specified:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="Raven/MaxPageSize" value="512" />
```

this change the maximum number of results that you retrive by default when querying.

Instead if we are talking about the default number of elements indexed in a single batch you need to know that default values are:

- 64-bit: 128 * 1024
- 32-bit: 64 * 1024

you can change this in the Raven.Server.exe.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Raven/MaxNumberOfItemsToIndexInSingleBatch" value="" />
```

Larger batch size result in faster indexing, but higher memory usage.